# My question was closed without an answer but I see other similar questions answered

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Network Engineering Stack Exchange post: [In an IGMP V2 membership report message, isn't the destination Ethernet address based on the multicast group IP address?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/70471/in-an-igmp-v2-membership-report-message-isnt-the-destination-ethernet-address)

What I was asking was very clearing stated as the subject/title, literally as a question. I don't see why that was unclear. The rest of the additional detail just gave the background for why I asked. I've since edited the body to remove those details so that just the question remains.
Other similar questions answered:

1. Minimum size of Ethernet/IGMP frames
   [Minimum possible size of Ethernet/IGMP frames](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/45130/minimum-possible-size-of-ethernet-igmp-frames)
2. Why TTL value 1 in IGMP
   [why TTL value 1 in IGMP](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/9636/why-ttl-value-1-in-igmp)

Answer (score -1):

The edit clears the confusion, and it has been reopened.

The other two questions are specifically about the protocol theory, but your original question confused what your host OS and driver were actually doing, which is off-topic.